# sort / max string with np.nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, object

pandas throws err when i try to get max of a string column that has `np.nan`, since `np.nan` is `float` type and can't be compared to `str`.

Any suggest how to handle this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters':['a', 'b', np.nan]})
df

# letters
# 0 a
# 1 b
# 2 NaN

for e in df['letters']:
    print(e, type(e))
    
# a <class 'str'>
# b <class 'str'>
# nan <class 'float'>
    
df['letters'].max()
```

gives err:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

----update-----

`dropna` works for simple sort/max, but doesn't work when there's `groupby`, since it will delete groups. Eg

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters':['a', 'b', np.nan, np.nan]
                  ,'grp': [1,1,1,2]})
df
#   letters grp
# 0 a   1
# 1 b   1
# 2 NaN 1
# 3 NaN 2
        
df.groupby('grp')['letters'].max()
# dropna will delete grp == 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue as you use the default, `float` NaN.

This works fine with the new [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) type, which you can obtain using [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) to have `string` type instead of `object`:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df['letters'].max()
# 'b'

df['letters'].max(skipna=False)
# <NA>
```

`df` after `convert_dtypes`:

```
  letters
0       a
1       b
2    <NA>
```

dtypes:

```
df.dtypes

letters    string
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could drop them first:

```
out = df['letters'].dropna().max()
```

If you need to find the max of multiple columns, then you could `stack` them; then use `groupby` + `max`:

```
out = df.stack().groupby(level=1).max()
```

Output:

```
'b'
```